# Loader for every server side transaction

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

How can i create a loading bar for all pages in an asp.net project,
according to the browser loading bar.
And prevent the user from taking another action while loading?
do i have to do it for all pages using site master, or for every single page?

I tried this code , but it is not compatible with firefox, only with IE 7 i think.
It stays whatever it is loading or not on the Firefox.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowProgress() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass("modal");
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
        }, 200);
    }
    $('form').live("submit", function () {
        ShowProgress();
    });
</script>

<div class="loading" align="center">
    Loading. Please wait.<br />
    <br />
    <img src="Style/images/loader.gif" />
</div>
```

---

```
            if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string script = "$(document).ready(function () { $('[id*=Search]').click(); });";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", script, true);
        }
```

and i cant add it on the sitemaster

Comment: i edited the post with the code i tried @harsha

Comment: Hi @M.Ghandour :) May be this example http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/10/jQuery-display-Progress-Bar-on-Button-Click-in-Aspnet.html
Helping You

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudeElghandour from ur link I found another link: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/10/how-to-show-progressbar-during.html , that use the postbacks of the pages

Comment: But this is not answering my whole question ?, it is not for the page loading (according to the browser).

Comment: see this link http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/queryLoader/

Comment: also this link http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#page

Comment: query loader is perfect, thats what i need.. Thanks very much @MahmoudeElghandour and thanks all, make it an answer

Comment: thanks man @M.Ghandour where are you from we have same family name :)

Comment: Egypt, 10th of ramadan city

Comment: Nice to meet you iam from sharkia zagazig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Update panel and update progress to create a loader for any server side loading:

ASPX (Web forms) code:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="progress" runat="server" DynamicLayout="true" DisplayAfter="0">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div id="overlay">
                <div id="modalprogress">
                    <div id="theprogress">
                        <div class="loading">
                            Loading&#8230;
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Comment: How to hide updateprogress? in my case once it appears it never goes away even after the activity is done.